# Parenting - Only the children moves when I move the parent and the parent stays still

Tags: parent

I have attached a few objects to a parent, but when I transform the parent, only the children are transformed while the parent stays the same. This is the case for positioning, rotation and scaling.

I recreated it in fresh scene with some boxes and it worked fine.

Thank you very much for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when you transform *only Origins*.
Parented object (children) are bound to the object's *origin*, not geometry.

*Example: Cube as parent, Suzanne as child.*

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! That is exactly what I needed.
Thank you very much for the video as well!

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.